MS Access Edge Browser Control to call a telephone number (W10)
I'm trying to create a simple form to show a phone number that a user can click to initiate a call.  The main issue is how to 'load' the html to be displayed as the Browser Control is designed to load a URL.
After a lot of hunting I have got the old Web Browser Control to do this.  It shows the link and a click opens the Windows pop-up asking which App to use.
Its replacement is the Edge Browser Control which is not compatible - it needs its own code.
After  lots of failed attempts, the code from HevHut here got me as far as loading the html.
Opening the form shows the phone number link but on clicking the link there is no pop-up - all that happens is that the form turns dark grey and does nothing.
The relevant code in the Form_Load even consists of:
w = "<a href='tel:5555555555'>call 5555555555</a>"
sJS = "document.open();document.write(""" & w & """);document.close();"
Me.EdgeBrowser2.Navigate "about:blank"
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until EdgeBrowser2.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE    'READYSTATE_COMPLETE=4
Me.EdgeBrowser2.ExecuteJavascript sJS

I have tried omitting lines 3 to 6 and it behaves exactly the same.
In contrast the old Browser Control code
Set webControl = Me.Wb.Object
With webControl
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until webControl.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE=4
    .Document.Write "<a href='tel:5555555555'>Call the store</a>"
End With

works.
Using the Edge browser control for a regular web site, or using identical code as at the top, but replacing the href string with a regular URL works just fine.
I tried a 'mailto:' link and that behaves exactly like the 'tel:'
Finally I tried 'mailx:' with the same result.
I conclude that there is no support for tel: and mailto: links.
Could there be some setting or other that has to be activated?

Just to confirm, you only want to invoke Windows' default tel: URI scheme handler for a given phone-number - but you're currently achieving this via the WebBrowser and/or WebView2 component? (If so, this might be a new record for the most unnecessary invocation of the Blink engine since Satan himself invented Electron.app)

I agree!  A day before I was looking at the new Edge control and sort of just slipped into the idea...

You really, really, do not need to pull-in an entire modern (and RAM-demolishing) browser engine just to have tel: (or callto:) URIs handled appropriately.
All you need is ShellExecute - which is already easily accessible in VBA/VB6:
1. Open Access' VBA editor:

2. Add a reference to Shell32:

2.1. Open the References window.
2.2. Add a reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"

(which should come from either C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll for 64-bit Office or C:\Windows\SysWow64\shell32.dll for 32-bit Office).

3. Write the Subroutine:
This Sub-routine simply passes any String-typed uri parameter down along to ShellExecute.
Sub OpenUri(uri As String)

    Dim shl As Shell32.Shell
    Set shl = New Shell32.Shell
    
    shl.ShellExecute uri


End Sub

It really is that simple. No Formula-1-race-car-just-to-go-to-the-shops web-browser engine required.

The screenshot below shows me trying to make a test call with the tel: URI scheme, and it shows Windows prompt me to choose Teams or Skype (or another browser) to handle the tel: URI because I don't actually have a default tel: handler set yet)



Very many thanks!  Not only an answer that works first time but beautifully crafted and presented!

While the above fully answers what I need, a definitive answer as to whether the Edge Browser Control can be made to recognise tel: and mailto: would be useful to know.

Just as an aside, you mentioned "(which should come from either C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll for 64-bit Office or C:\Windows\SysWow64\shell32.dll for 32-bit Office)."  I have 64 bit Office installed.  All my referenced libraries are shown to be in 64 bit folders but selecting 'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation' shows it to be in SysWOW64 library - very strange.
